# dplyr sub-setting by group, excluding NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

If I have a data.frame: `dat = data.frame(shape1 = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), date = c(today() - 0:3), value = c(1, 2, NA, 16))`

Then run:

```
dat %>% dplyr::group_by(shape1) %>% dplyr::slice(base::which.max(date[!is.na(value)]))
```

Why are there `NA`s in `value`?

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups: shape1 [2]
  shape1 date       value
  <chr>  <date>     <dbl>
1 a      2018-10-02  1.00
2 b      2018-09-30  NA
```

Shouldn't `[!is.na(value)]` exclude them?
This returns what I'm looking for

```
dat %>% dplyr::group_by(shape1) %>% dplyr::filter(!is.na(value)) %>% dplyr::slice(base::which.max(date))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups: shape1 [2]
  shape1 date       value
  <chr>  <date>     <dbl>
1 a      2018-10-02  1.00
2 b      2018-09-29  16.0
```

However, I'm confused as to why the first one returns an NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to the subsetting.  So, after the subset, the index returned is 1 for 'shape1' 'b' which happens to be the row where the NA element in the original data is present.  It would be better to `filter` first.  However, one can use `==` with the `max` value and select the first element (in case of ties)

```
dat %>%
    group_by(shape1) %>% 
    slice(which(date == max(date[!is.na(value)]))[1])
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   shape1 [2]
#  shape1 date       value
#  <fct>  <date>     <dbl>
#1 a      2018-10-02     1
#2 b      2018-09-29    16
```

Comment: So is it an order of operations issue? Is `dplyr` slicing by `date` before checking for `NA` in values?

Comment: @R.M.  the which.max returns the index of the elements subsettted and not the original data index, but when it goes into `slice`, the index 1 means the  row 1 of the group